# How to retrieve data from Mysql database using a timer?

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin.android

I need to retrieve data from a Mysql database in xamarin android using a timer. The timer has a intervale of 1s. The database is indexed with a auto incremental column named "id". I trying to obtain the last row of data in the database.
with the last row I need to obtain the values ​​of 3 columns. Each column is an int type.

However I am getting the following exception:

```
No current query in data reader
```

With the following code:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        parts = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.partslabel);

        Timer timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.Interval = 2000;
        timer1.Elapsed += Timer1_Elapsed;

        timer1.Start();

    }

    private void Timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        retrievefromdb();
    }

    public void retrievefromdb()
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=192.168.15.88; Port=3306; database=database01;uid=user;pwd=userpass;");          
            try
            {

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

                    connection.Open();
                    using (MySqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (myReader.Read())
                        {

                            RunOnUiThread(() =>
                            {                                    
                                parts.Text = myReader["parts"].ToString();
                            });

                        }
                    }

                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                    syslog.Text = ex.ToString();
                });
            }                       
    }
} 
}
```

the exception is thrown in the line:

```
parts.Text = myReader["parts"].ToString();
```

If i tried to run the code using a button instead of the timer. It works perfectly.

I thought the fail was because the function of the data reader was not being disposed but after placing the function inside a using block it continued to fail.

How I can to retrieve data from Mysql database using a timer? Maybe the path I'm following is not the appropriate or the simplest one.

Comment: The timer is running on its own thread.  I suspect that's part of your problem.  Is there any way you can pass the reader into the `RunOnUIThread` call via that lambda expression?

Comment: That works!  I put the `retrievefromdb()` function in the lambda expression. Thanks . I think that I don't understand well the timer function or the lambda expression.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Can you put your comment in an answer? please.